# Integer logarithms

Tags: code-golf, math, number, arithmetic

Given integers `N , P > 1` , find the largest integer `M` such that `P ^ M ≤ N`.

#### I/O:

Input is given as 2 integers `N` and `P`. The output will be the integer `M`.

#### Examples:

```
4, 5 -> 0
33, 5 -> 2
40, 20 -> 1
242, 3 -> 4 
243, 3 -> 5 
400, 2 -> 8
1000, 10 -> 3
```

#### Notes:

The input will always be valid, i.e. it will always be integers greater than 1.

#### Credits:

Credit for the name goes to @cairdcoinheringaahing. The last 3 examples are by @Nitrodon and credit for improving the description goes to @Giuseppe.

Comment: I know we (the PPCG community) can seem to be overly nit-picky about really small stuff, but comments like mine are really intended, in good faith, to make the challenge better! Now that that's been resolved, I have happily up-voted, and deleted my previous comments.

Comment: That's another reason why we suggest posting challenges into [The Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges?cb=1) first, so that you can receive helpful feedback, post a great challenge, and get lots of high-quality answers, with much less fuss (like close- and down- votes). :)

Comment: You can always post into [the general PPCG Chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/240/the-nineteenth-byte) asking for feedback on your sandbox challenges to get them a bit more attention.

Comment: Suggested test cases: one where `P ^ M = N`, and one where `M = 0` (if you don't plan to exclude the latter case).

Comment: @Nitrodon : Suggested values ?

Comment: I've edited the title to describe the challenge more - feel free to make your own changes

Comment: Can we take input as a list of integers? `[n,p]` instead of `n,p`

Comment: So I realized I could shave off 5 bytes with reversed order on input -see my Mathematica answer, which begs the question, is the order strict?

Comment: Didnt't you mean in the IO section: ... while output will be integer **`M`**?

Comment: Almost all of the current answers based on floating-point math produce wrong results even for simple cases like (1000, 10) because of rounding error, so I added another test case.

Comment: [**Meta post](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16250/31516)** about this challenge.

Comment: @Giuseppe : Please don't delete comments. Now I have no idea what you're talking about. Deleting comments makes responses completely contextless and usually meaningless.

Comment: @MPW all the responses were deleted, and the suggestions I made were edited into the post, so they were no longer relevant.

Answer (score 8):

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak), 74 bytes

```
(({}<>)[()])({()<(({})<({([{}]()({}))([{}]({}))}{})>){<>({}[()])}{}>}[()])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMzTTctJzP7/X0OjutbGTjNaQzNWU6NaQ9MGJAAkqzWiq2tjNTRBPE0IG8SqBRJ2mtU2dkAeWA9QwA7C@v/fSMHEwAAA)

This uses the same concept as the standard Brain-Flak positive integer division algorithm.

```
# Push P and P-1 on other stack
(({}<>)[()])

# Count iterations until N reaches zero:
({()<

  # While keeping the current value (P-1)*(P^M) on the stack:
  (({})<

    # Multiply it by P for the next iteration
    ({([{}]()({}))([{}]({}))}{})

  >)

  # Subtract 1 from N and this (P-1)*(P^M) until one of these is zero
  {<>({}[()])}{}

# If (P-1)*(P^M) became zero, there is a nonzero value below it on the stack
>}

# Subtract 1 from number of iterations
[()])
```

Answer (score 7):

## JavaScript (ES6), 22 bytes

*Saved 8 bytes thanks to @Neil*

Takes input in currying syntax `(p)(n)`.

```javascript
p=>g=n=>p<=n&&1+g(n/p)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XclBDkAwEADAu1f0JLsRSkviYP2lQRsi2wbx/SJxYa6zmNPswzaHI2c/TtFSDNQ7YupDR5ymVeaAZcA4eN79OhWrd2ChQdAaUQgphUq@p0qEurzzvup/T73Xxgs)

Answer (score 6):

## Excel, 18 bytes

```
=TRUNC(LOG(A1,A2))
```

Takes input "n" at A1, and input "p" at A2.

Comment: I think you can use `INT` function instead of `TRUNC` to save 2 bytes.

Answer (score 5):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 3 bytes

```
bḊL
```

This doesn't use floating-point arithmetic, so there are no precision issues.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z/p4Y4un//FRtZKh5cb6bv//29srKNgqqNgYqCjYGQAokEMIDIBEsYg2hhMm4BVGRqApA0NAA)

#### How it works

```
bḊL  Main link. Left argument: n. Right argument: p

b    Convert n to base p.
 Ḋ   Dequeue; remove the first base-p digit.
  L  Take the length.
```

Answer (score 3):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 25 bytes

```r
function(p,n)log(p,n)%/%1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfpmCjq/A/rTQvuSQzP0@jQCdPMyc/HUyr6qsa/k/TMDEw0DHS/A8A)

Take the log of `P` base `N` and do integer division with `1`, as it's shorter than `floor()`. This suffers a bit from numerical precision, so I present the below answer as well, which should not, apart from possibly integer overflow.

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 31 bytes

```r
function(p,n)(x=p:0)[n^x<=p][1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfpmCj@z@tNC@5JDM/T6NAJ09To8K2wMpAMzovrsLGtiA22jD2f5qGiYGBjpHmfwA)

Comment: I don't know how strict the challenge requires us to be on rounding error but for example, f(243,3) is equal to 4 when it probably is required to be 5.

Comment: @JDL that's a fair point; I believe a perfectly precise answer would be ~31 bytes.

Comment: I think you can replace `p` by `p+.1` in the 25 byte answer and you will still be okay, for 28 bytes

Comment: [Another 28 byte solution](https://tio.run/##K/qfpmCj@z@tNC@5JDM/T6NAJ0@zuDRXIy9Oo8DKUNPGtkDzf5qGkYmxjrHmfwA "R – Try It Online") without numerical precision issues.

Answer (score 3):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/) + `-lm`, 24 bytes

```c
f(n,m){n=log(n)/log(m);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z9NI08nV7M6zzYnP10jT1MfROVqWtf@z03MzNPQrC4oyswrSdNQUk1R0knTMDbWMdUEyf5LTstJTC/@r5uTCwA)

Comment: I know about `long long` but what is `bytes bytes`? :P

Comment: Also flags don't add to your byte count anymore, so I edited to reflect this.

Comment: Doesn't work for (1000, 10) because of rounding error.

Comment: `f(n,m){n=(float)log(n)/log(m);}` seems to work @31 bytes

Answer (score 3):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 35 bytes

```
.+
$*
+r`1*(\2)+¶(1+)$
#$#1$*1¶$2
#
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P9fT5tLRYtLuyjBUEsjxkhT@9A2DUNtTRUuZRVlQxUtw0PbVIy4lP//NzbmMgUA) Explanation:

```
.+
$*
```

Convert the arguments to unary.

```
+r`1*(\2)+¶(1+)$
#$#1$*1¶$2
```

If the second argument divides the first, replace the first argument with a `#` plus the integer result, discarding the remainder. Repeat this until the first argument is less than the second.

```
#
```

Count the number of times the loop ran.

Answer (score 3):

## Japt, 8 bytes

```
@<Vp°X}a
```

[Try it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=QDxWcLBYfWE=&input=NDAwLDI=)

Comment: This is really neat, I haven't really seen a good use for the function methods in Japt yet, this is a good example.

Comment: @Nit, it took me a good while to get to grips with them, too - only recently started figuring out uses for `F.g()` - but they're incredibly useful.

Answer (score 3):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 16 bytes

```hs
(floor.).logBase
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7NyfmfZhvzXyMtJz@/SE9TLyc/3SmxOPV/bmJmnoKtQkFRZl6JgopCmoKpgrHx/3/JaTmJ6cX/dZMLCgA)

Haskell was designed by mathematicians so it has a nice set of math-related functions in Prelude.

Comment: Doesn't work for (1000, 10) because of rounding error.

Answer (score 3):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 30 bytes

```hs
n!p=until((>n).(p^).(1+))(1+)0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P0@xwLY0ryQzR0PDLk9TT6MgDkgYamtqggiD/7mJmXm2BUWZeSUqXApVmQXhmSUZGoqa0cbGOiYGQGQQG22qY2SgYxT7HwA)

Comment: Either `until((>n).(p^))(1+)0-1` or `until(\x->p^x*p>n)(1+)0` gets you down to 27 bytes.

Answer (score 3):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 13 bytes

```perl6
&floor∘&log
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJZq@18tLSc/v@hRxwy1nPz0/9ZcxYkgcQ0TAwMdI00419hYx1TzPwA)

Concatenation composing log and floor, implicitly has 2 arguments because first function log expects 2. Result is a function.

Comment: For arguments `1000, 10` this returns 2.

Comment: @Sean: Huh, interesting precision issue there

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 39 bytes

```python
lambda a,b:math.log(a,b)//1
import math
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUSFRJ8kqN7EkQy8nP10DyNHU1zfkyswtyC8qUQCJ/y8oyswr0UjT0MrMKygt0dDU1PxvbKyjYAoA)

Comment: 1000,10 as inputs gives 2 as output.

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 5 bytes

```
ìV ÊÉ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osKPn///CaMIXDXYc7//83MTDgMgIA)

---

### 8 bytes

```
N£MlXÃäz
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osKPn/3@/QYt@ciMPNh5dU/f9vYmCgYwQA)

Comment: Was about to post the same thing using `ì` instead of `s` as `s` will fail if `V>36`.

Comment: @Shaggy Good call on `V>36`.

Answer (score 2):

## [JavaScript](https://nodejs.org), <s>40</s> 33 bytes

*-3 bytes thanks to DanielIndie*

Takes input in currying syntax.

```javascript
a=>b=>(L=Math.log)(a)/L(b)+.001|0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Zc5NCoMwEAXgfU/hcoZSM/kRuokn0ENEq/1BjFTpyrunmYKljW/7wXvv4V5ubp/3aTmN/tKF3gZny8aWUNnaLbd88FcEh6KCBo85kVwptH6c/dCxQQ9aIxSIWYwQmTr8qyEERR@OKnfKvOk5UWUUgt7U7FT/aJE2f0@xUqKSeFjyr6g6vAE)

Comment: [29 bytes](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@18jUSdJx8fWN7EkQy8nP13T1s5HI1FT30cjSbPG4H9yfl5xfk4qSEYjTcPYWMdU09bWSFNBQUFfX8GIC1XaxEDHyAAob6gJljbEkAbKA6UtINIW/wE)

Comment: [28 bytes](https://tio.run/##ZcpLDkAwEIDhvVN0ObOgVSQ20xNwiPEmooJYuXu9VmL7f//AO6/l0s@bP9mqdg05JlOQgYxy3rpgtC0Co8ygwEO50k6rHes7QwNRhJAgkUYhhJRCe1@PFYJW1xDi4@HP7@Hy9PXUnQ) and maybe if you want curry method

Comment: @nwellnhof https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@z/R1i7J1k7Dx9Y3sSRDLyc/XVMjUVPfRyNJs8bgf3J@XnF@TipIWCNNw9DAwEATSGpqKigo6OsrGHOhypsAZY3AskBJQwxJkCxU0uI/AA

Comment: [Doesn't work for (999, 10)](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@z/R1i7J1k7Dx9Y3sSRDLyc/XVMjUVPfRyNJU1vPwMCwxuB/cn5ecX5OKkhOI03D0tJSU8PQQFPzPwA) (should output 2)

Comment: @Oliver The smallest problem I could find is 17179869183 (2^34-1) and 2, which should output 33 but instead outputs 34. In general, there exists a large enough n such that 2^n-1 and 2 produce the wrong output, for any number in place of .001

Comment: @HermanLauenstein I think I have a new workaround.

Comment: The `toString` solution only works for bases up to 36.

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 6 bytes

```
Lm¹›_O
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f/fJ/fQzkcNu@L9//83NDAw4DI0AAA)

Comment: this just seems unfair to everyone else

Comment: @Floris Competitions are between submissions in each language not between languages right?

Comment: @user202729 yes and no. In my mind, in the end, "shortest code wins". But I noticed there was a 2-byte solution further down... These golf languages blow my mind.

Comment: @Floris "Don't let code-golf languages discourage you from posting answers with non-codegolfing languages. Try to come up with an as short as possible answer for 'any' programming language."

Comment: @Floris Also... [even Excel can do it in 2 builtins](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/162713). Golfing languages can do this in 2 built-in too, just the builtin names are shorter. Nothing to surprise.

Answer (score 2):

## [Emojicode](http://www.emojicode.org/), <s>49</s> 48 bytes

```
ij➡️➖i j 1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S83Nz8pMzk9J/f9hfn@jwof5ve1cCiBqWVppXvJ/ED/zw/xZTVkg4tG8he939INYQPG@R/OmfZg/YcqH@VMWZipkKRgCxTr/g/TOaFAACYJMWasAMkbB0MDAAEgAERdYFQA)

Answer (score 2):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 2 bytes

```apl
⌊⍟
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///P@1R24RHPV2Peuf//2@qkKZgbMxlZACkTQy4jMCUAQA)

Pretty straightforward.

`⍟` Log

`⌊` floor

Comment: Make dyadic to save a byte: [`⌊⍟`](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///P@1R24RHPV2Peuf//2@qkKZgbMxlZACkTQy4jMCUAQA "APL (Dyalog Unicode) – Try It Online")

Comment: I'm slightly ashamed you actually had to tell me that >.> thanks, though!

Answer (score 2):

## Pari/GP, 6 bytes

```
logint
```

(built-in added in version 2.7, Mar 2014.  Takes two arguments, with an optional third reference which, if present, is set to the base raised to the result)

Comment: @StewieGriffin logint(x,y) from both Pari/GP and Perl/ntheory give the correct results for the 7 examples currently shown, including '3' for 1000,10.

Comment: +1, but I would count this as 6 bytes.

Comment: You're not allowed to use hardcoded inputs, so this must be a function (eg. as a lambda or definition). However you can just use `logint` which is valid and counts 5 bytes less.

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 31 bytes

OK, so all those log-based approaches are prone to rounding errors, so here is another method that works with integers and is free of those issues:

```ruby
->n,p{(0..n).find{|i|p**i>n}-1}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Pcw7CoAwEEXR3lUM2KjEMMlEsNGNiI1IIE0IgoWoa4/5qK888O62L4fXg29Hy9xZIee25trY9bzM5ZrGjPZuxe0d6ImIQTdDWAmyiKKQgcQ5iXglUpY@iVSSAWVRr9AvXX594SCYRGAMidAugfwD)

But going back to logarithms, although it is unclear up to what precision we must support the input, but I think this little trick would solve the rounding problem for all more or less "realistic" numbers:

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 29 bytes

```ruby
->n,p{Math.log(n+0.1,p).to_i}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y5Pp6DaN7EkQy8nP10jT9tAz1CnQFOvJD8@s/Z/gUJatLGxjoJprAIQKCsYcYFETAx0FIwMYsEihlARkBBExAIsYmRipKNgDBExgYoYw0VMIbpgBgNFDMAihgYggwyBZisrGP8HAA)

Answer (score 2):

## Python 2, 3, 46 bytes

*-1 thanks to jonathan*

```
def A(a,b,i=1):
 while b**i<=a:i+=1
 return~-i
```

### Python 1, 47 bytes

```
def A(a,b,i=1):
 while b**i<=a:i=i+1
 return~-i
```

Comment: `n~-i` is one byte shorter than `n i-1`.

Comment: Also, please state your Python's version.

Comment: Will work in any version, won't it?

Comment: It will not work in Python 1.

Answer (score 2):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 22 bytes

```javascript
m=>f=n=>n<m?0:f(n/m)+1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY/BDsIgDIbve4oeAVEZjMQZmQ@ycFjmXDTCzLb4@pOWHUj6/f1o4d39uqWfX9/1GKfHsI1uC655uuiaeAt3dX2yeA78UG7rsKwLOGgLgLaSYCUoL6E1hmqNdaVSkU6JoCstITWrDIbAZg09CReEuq7TBbVPKBX2EI2XuEkLYfWxJN/muZhk1tkxQhhycAc5lGTeHSuEJgffSg4lmbUvfFHQD0@h@zLWRglBwuw5uAb6KS7TZzh9ppGNLHAWU@xg5nz7Aw)

Curried recursive function. Use as `g(P)(N)`. Less prone to floating-point errors than [using `Math.log`](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/162720/78410), and (I believe) the code gives correct values as long as both inputs are safe integers (under `2**52`).

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>35</s> 34 bytes

```hs
n!p=last.fst$span((<=n).(p^))[0..]
```

Thanks @Laikoni for saving 1 byte

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcJBCoAgEADAr6zQQUFEtG75jg5i4KFQsmXJPfV5a5iS@3W0NgYKCi13NmfnqVNGKdeAykjalYrWmDTuXBEC0FORYYK30la5gBQKovd6tn@bIC7aWe3S@AA)

Answer (score 1):

## Pyth, <strike>6</strike> 4 bytes

```
s.lF
```

Saved 2 bytes thanks to Mmenomic
[Try it online](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=s.lhQe&input=400%2C+2&debug=1)

### How it works

`.l` is log<sub>B</sub>(A)
To be honest, I have no idea how `F` works. But if it works, it works.
`s` truncates a float to an int to give us the highest integer for `M`.

Comment: 1000,10 as inputs gives 2 as output

Comment: Another similar solution is `/FlM`

Answer (score 1):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), <s>8</s> <s>7</s> 4 bytes

```
Lt`B
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv6fe2h5arFGsdujpsb/PiUJTv///4/WMDbWMdXU0TAx0DEyANNABpA2MjHSMQbTxmDaBKzK0AAobWigGQsA)

Answer (score 1):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 5 bytes

```
<.@^.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/bfQc4vT@a3JxpSZn5CuYKqQpGBtD2EYGQI6JAZQDZhtw/QcA)

Answer (score 1):

### Wolfram Language (Mathematica) <s>15</s> 10 Bytes

```
Floor@*Log
```

(requires reversed order on input)

Original submission

```
⌊#2~Log~#⌋&
```

Comment: `⌊Log@##⌋&` is one byte shorter

Comment: @Mathe172, that's one character shorter, but I count 13 bytes on that. The left floor and right floor count as 3 bytes each in UTF-8.

Comment: @StewieGriffin %[10,1000] gives 3. The inputs are treated as integers rather than machine numbers unless you put a decimal place after them.

Answer (score 1):

## [Forth (gforth)](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/forth/gforth/Docs-html/), 35 bytes

```forth
: f swap s>f flog s>f flog f/ f>s ;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TcxBCoAgFIThvaf4L1CJ2qbAu0TwbBEYGnR8s0XZ6s3HDE9iOrcuyHNKmRDytRxkL8geQwsyID4zF2thpA571qScBqObNObrjDPYV1TaRuX4vSk3)

Could save 5 bytes by swapping expected input parameters, but question specifies N must be first (an argument could be made that in a postfix language "First" means top-of-stack, but I'll stick to the letter of the rules for now)

### Explanation

```forth
swap       \ swap the parameters to put N on top of the stack
s>f flog   \ move N to the floating-point stack and take the log(10) of N
s>f flog   \ move P to the floating-point stack and take the log(10) of P
f/         \ divide log10(N) by log10(P)
f>s        \ move the result back to the main (integer) stack, truncating in the process
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Wonder](https://github.com/wonderlang/wonder), 9 bytes

```
|_.sS log
```

Example usage:

```
(|_.sS log)[1000 10]
```

## Explanation

Verbose version:

```
floor . sS log
```

This is written pointfree style. `sS` passes list items as arguments to a function (in this case, `log`).

Answer (score 1):

## [Gforth](https://www.gnu.org/software/gforth/), 31 Bytes

```
SWAP S>F FLOG S>F FLOG F/ F>S .
```

### Usage

```
242 3 SWAP S>F FLOG S>F FLOG F/ F>S . 4 OK
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8svKsnQTU8DUf@NTIwUjP8HhzsGKATbuSm4@fi7Ixhu@gpudsEKev@BAAA)

### Explanation

Unfortunately FORTH uses a dedicated floating-point-stack. For that i have to `SWAP` (exchange) the input values so they get to the floating point stack in the right order. I also have to move the values to that stack with `S>F`. When moving the floating-point result back to integer (`F>S`) I have the benefit to get the truncation for free.

### Shorter version

Stretching the requirements and provide the input in float-format and the right order, there is a shorter version with 24 bytes.

```
FLOG FSWAP FLOG F/ F>S .
3e0 242e0 FLOG FSWAP FLOG F/ F>S . 4 OK
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8svKsnQTU8DUf@NUw0UjEyMUg3@u/n4uyu4BYc7BihAmPoKbnbBCnr/gQAA)

Comment: Generally for CodeGolf answers, [snippets](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2419/default-for-code-golf-program-function-or-snippet) are disallowed (unless otherwise indicated in the challenge). This answer should either be wrapped with a function (Word in Forth) `: f .... ;` or a converted to a  program that takes input using `KEY` or `ACCEPT`

Comment: @reffu What is a snippet? In my opinion a smal code part to show something, which, however, does nothing meaningful for itself. On the other hand, the code that I've provided does work without changes on "Try it online!".  Should we go meta?

Comment: In this particular case the code you posted will in fact throw a stack underflow unless you place the parameters before it. Code golf answers should generally be a self-contained program or function that produces the expected result if called later. If you follow the link to the meta post in my previous comment it explicitly mentions that the standard is for answers to be a program or a function, of which yours is neither. To fix it would only require another 4 bytes

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 61 bytes

```c
i(n,t,l,o,g){for(l=g=0;!g++;g=g>n)for(o=++l;o--;g*=t);g=--l;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RczJboMwFAXQdfMVN1RINhjJGNPJcvMTWXYTMViWwKDALsq3U5uhXTw9v2PdW2WmqpbFEsdm1rGBGfpohzvptNFcnU2aKqPNt6MBB52mnRqyTJlEz9T/ZFmnnstr3bTWNbj6FowMPcV4t25uSWRJLGuGWNQUOizoy7pIPNEfFzFsEbtGqc/@vaE1elwQjbdpauoIX4gSN8wJdqDq1N@sI/RxerkSoCgYUPoRdAPJGYQf5BtIHg7h52MDIcMRYvKAYody74DcS/kKOQ8deegpVpD8s9xK8/yAtx3EAe//8Fx@AQ)

Answer (score 1):

## PowerShell 3,  <s>44</s> 38 Bytes

```
param($n,$p)for(;($n/=$p)-ge1){$z++}$z
```

Truncating to an int is too dang long in this language. However, looting the formula others are using bypasses this. <s>Crossed-out 44 is still 44</s>

Answer (score 1):

## x86(16/32 bit) opcode, 13 bytes

```
83 CB FF  31 DB  F7 F1  43  09 C0  75 F7  C3
```

Input `EAX`, `ECX`, output `EBX`

```
OR  EBX, -1
XOR EDX, EDX
DIV ECX
INC EBX
OR  EAX, EAX
JNZ $-7
RET
```

Comment: Although this is one of the shortest answers, it could do with at least some explanation (preferably a disassembly, so that mortals can *see* which registers are used, and which opcodes).

Comment: But 32 bit division not use edx? So edx it is not initialized to 0?

Comment: @RosLuP Fixed..

Answer (score 1):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 5 bytes

```
:YAnq
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/3yrSMa/w/39jLiMTYwA)

Simple arbitrary base conversion to avoid using floating point math.

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>29</s> 26 bytes

```ruby
f=->n,p{n<p ?0:1+f[n/p,p]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Jcw5DoAwDETRq7jHgLPQIJaDWCmSIh2RhUSBgLOHBKp5xdfsRzhzjnO7JJQrTQIrjaqJnHpBcU9mNgZhcMiWEDR9qCrQViOYD@aH/VNFNVHkXLd5uW6P4RaIXLZcvg)

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://pyth.readthedocs.io), 8 bytes

```
tf<Q^vzT
```

[Test suite.](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=tf%3CQ%5EvzT&input=400%0A2&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=4%0A5%0A%0A33%0A5%0A%0A40%0A20%0A%0A242%0A3%0A%0A243%0A3%0A%0A400%0A2%0A%0A1000%0A10%0A&debug=0&input_size=3)

### Explanation

```
tf<Q^vzT – Full program.
 f       – First positive integer T that satsfies:
   Q       – The first input
  <        – Is less than
     vz    – The second input
    ^  T   – Raised to the T-th power.
t        – Decrement the integer and output implicitly.
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Intel 8087 FPU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_8087) assembly, 38 bytes

Uses only the Intel 8087 math co-processor.

```
d9e8 df06 3c01 d9f1 d9e8 df06 3e01 d9f1 def9 9bd9
3e3e 0181 0e3e 0100 0c9b d92e 3e01 df1e 3c01
```

Unassembled:

```
; Integer logarithm
; input: integers N, P > 1 (mem16,mem16)
; output: N (mem16) largest integer such that P ^ M ≤ N
INTLOG  MACRO N,P
        FLD1        ; ST(1) = 1
        FILD N      ; ST = N
        FYL2X       ; ST = 1 * LOG2(N)
        FLD1        ; ST(1) = 1
        FILD P      ; ST = P
        FYL2X       ; ST = 1 * LOG2(P)
        FDIV        ; ST = LOG2(N) / LOG2(P)
        FWAIT       ; sync CPU/FPU
        FSTCW P     ; get the current CW register
        OR P, 0C00H ; set RC for floor rounding mode
        FWAIT       ; sync CPU/FPU
        FLDCW P     ; set the modified CW register
        FISTP N     ; N = FLOOR(ST)
        ENDM
```

Example IBM PC DOS test program:

```
    FINIT           ; reset 8087
    CALL INDEC      ; generic decimal input routine
    MOV  N, AX      ; first input into N
    CALL INDEC      ; generic decimal input routine
    MOV  P, AX      ; second input into P
    INTLOG N,P      ; calculate
    MOV  AX, N      ; result in N into AX for display
    CALL OUTDEC     ; generic decimal output routine
```

### Tests:

```
A>INTDEC.COM
: 4
: 5
0
A>INTDEC.COM
: 33
: 5
2
A>INTDEC.COM
: 40
: 20
1
A>INTDEC.COM
: 242
: 3
4
A>INTDEC.COM
: 243
: 3
5
A>INTDEC.COM
: 400
: 2
8
A>INTDEC.COM
: 1000
: 10
3
```

*Note*: **16 bytes** of this code are *just* for putting the FPU into floor rounding mode.

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/) with [mpmath](http://mpmath.org/doc/current/), 52 bytes

```
import mpmath
def f(N,P):return int(mpmath.log(N,P))
```

Test it:

```
for N, P in zip([4, 33, 40, 242, 243, 400, 1000], [5, 5, 20, 3, 3, 2, 10]):
    print(f(N,P))
```

How I would really do it. The mpmath (included with SymPy) logarithm seems more accurate, even at default. I always love some arbitrary precision floating-point. I was really surprised that the standard methods led to such inaccuracies.

Answer (score 1):

## [Keg](https://github.com/JonoCode9374/Keg), `-hr`,  19 bytes

```
¿&¿0{:^:'$Ë&:&≤|⑨};
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASoA1f9rZWf//8K/JsK/MHs6XjonJMOLJjom4omkfOKRqH07//80MDAKMv8taHI)

Uses the same technique as the Pyth answer

### Explained

[image: With Highlighter]

Answer (score 1):

## [Wren](https://github.com/munificent/wren), 32 bytes

Log, log, floor.

```
Fn.new{|a,b|(a.log/b.log).floor}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Ky9KzftfllikkFaal6xgq/DfLU8vL7W8uiZRJ6lGI1EvJz9dPwlEauql5eTnF9X@D64sLknN1SsvyixJ1QDp0ktOzMnRMDEw0DHS1PwPAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Lua](https://www.lua.org), <strike>47</strike> 37 bytes

```lua
(N,P)return math.floor(math.log(N,P))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yylN/O@mYKuQVpqXXJKZn/dfw08nQLMotaS0KE8hN7EkQy8tJz@/SAPMzMlPB0tr/k/NS@EqKMrMK9Fw0zA21jEFCgEA)

Thanks to *@user9549915* for saving 10 bytes

Answer (score 0):

### PHP, 43 Bytes

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jXwAk00rzkksy8/MU0jRUCnRU8jSrU5Mz8hUy80rKEnM0cvLTocKa1rX/0zRMDAx0jDSt/wMA)

**Code**

```
function f($p,$n){echo intval(log($p,$n));}
```

`intval()` truncates a float number, as for `log($p,$n)` the integer part of the result will always be the maximum positive integer that satisfies the inequation.

### 34 Bytes

If passing arguments to the script

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jX5BRwKWSWJReFm0Qa2tiYGAN5RnG2hpZc9nbAZXYZuaVlCXmaOTkp2vAlOrAVGlqWv//DwA)

**Code**

```
<?=intval(log($argv[0],$argv[1]));
```

Comment: @FransiscoHahn : This is code-golf so you might wanna shorten your code ?

Answer (score 0):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 31 bytes

```ruby
->n,p,d=0{n<p**(d+=1)?d-1:redo}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y5Pp0AnxdagOs@mQEtLI0Xb1lDTPkXX0KooNSW/9n@BQlq0sbGOgmmsgoKyghEXiG9ioKNgZBAL5BtC@SABEN8CzDcyMdJRMAbxTaB8YyjfFKIeYhyQb/AfAA)

Curse you, floating point errors

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>40</s> 39 bytes

-1 @Jonathan

```python
g=lambda n,p,a=1:a*p<=n and-~g(n,p,a*p)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY69asMwGEV3P8UlGWwHJdiWAsVUQ5ZAoX@70aDWPw1pZKFoaBDqq7uynTTDHc7h@y5XX@xXr@gwdPxbnj5qCUU0kTwv5Uo/cgWp6vVvl0x2pdPBNmd7BkcVAViGvIa8Ay8jVwClBNgSFIJcDcsCheQ3w7JAKAgebqZggRA@2d3Q2Wz/e8Dm5uxq8mzsyUOoEFHU9mbejoPCtLIcz2DC2Gl/OqE2B2WTdtEmTnnitE9LND@6@bRNDSc9QddbOFPWfgO4Kt7vnp5jEr8d5SUWleTcCL9ZpMMf)

Comment: Don't you need the `g=` in order for this to work? My understanding has always been that unnamed functions are OK, except in cases like this where the function is referred to by name elsewhere (as in recursive functions).  So for example, `(lambda n,p,a=1:a*p<=n and g(n,p,a*p)+1)(5, 5)` will obviously produce an error, but instead I can do `g=lambda n,p,a=1:a*p<=n and g(n,p,a*p)+1` and then call `g(5,5)`.  [Unless maybe a new consensus has emerged about this...?]

Comment: @mathmandan - you are correct, my bad.  fixed.

Comment: `expected 0, got False.  Okay.`...

Comment: @Jonathan, in a numeric context False has the value 0.

Comment: @RootTwo I know, it just looked funny to call that `Okay.`. You could have used `{r:d}` in your string formatting.

Comment: Can `and g(...)+1` not be `and-~g(...)`?

Answer (score 0):

## PHP, 28 bytes

```
<?=log($argv[1],$argv[2])|0;
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fxt42Jz9dQyWxKL0s2jBWB8IwitWsMbD@//@/oYGBAZAAAA)

Comment: saved 3 bytes : https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jb/s/Jz9dQyWxKL0s2jBWB8IwitWsMbD@//@/oYGBAZAAAA

Comment: That wouldn't be valid; the `<?=` is required.

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org/), 22 bytes

```
{(1,*×$^p...*>$^n)-2}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Jco9DkAwAAbQq3yRRhCa/jG1PQox6OQvTA3O4UAOVqTbG946bGMTJo/UwYQj42Xx3KRdKaWFJe2cV@IKe@@RkA7G4nA4SXclcMsGLSVqW0IrBsEiPv0QSkBGyAgVK2df4cyGFw)

`1, * × $^p ... * > $^n` is a sequence that starts with 1, where each succeeding element is generated from the previous by multiplying by `$^p` (the second argument to the function), and continues up to the element `*` such that `*` is greater than `$^n` (the first argument to the function).  Subtracting two from this sequence coerces it to a number, specifically its length.  Two less than the length is the desired integer logarithm.

Answer (score 0):

## [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/), 39 bytes

```
proc L n\ p {expr int(log($n)/log($p))}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LcpBCsIwEIXh/ZziUWbRrJwmcaNX6A3URSkiQkyHGkEoOXscpJvvh8crc2pN12XGiHyFYrt/dcUzlz4tj56zO/yrztWWXpPuL4o4UghGFHghHz2CGcwoNtEglkGoYtNPeaPjfGY94TKCM1hvXW0/)

Gives `4` for `(243,3)` as it is the integer truncation of `4.99999999999999...`! The same happens when I tried other answers!

Comment: Darn rounding errors >:(

Answer (score 0):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>41</s> 31 bytes

Thanks to [Kevin](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52210/kevin-cruijssen) for his suggestion, which is reproduced below:

```c
f(n,p,m){for(;n/=p;m++);n=m-2;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY7LDoIwEEXX9CsmGE0rRYG4q/gjhgWWVxMYmlLcEL69UqML3c099yR3ZNxK6XYKZT9XNVwnW6nx1N3ID@rVY2Ouocg1H9jSjIYKPOdaDFHEBOZDnInVKbQwlAqpP0rTSg6yKw0cfXjeCwYLCT6kxkqQoB@xBYQcJmvs2NO3lxYcDlvPIU3YV9J/UvYnabONNjTcVyEH/yho5rmp7WwQEkFW5y5J4rIX)

Previous submission:

```c
f(n,p){int m;for(m=0;n/=p;m++);return m;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY7LDoIwEEXX8BUTjKaVqoW4q/gjhgWWVxMYmlLcEL69AsGF7Oaee5K58lJJ6Q4KZTPkBTx6m6vuWj/9P9So98xcSZBpOiq00IqyM6RNuMBbokUbhlSYwg4G52pyq5IpJMuRmUoykHVm4LyEzyulMPreRgrMhe81HVaAkEBvje0asnpRyuA09wwiTn@S3knxTtJmflqS4JgHDJbJoOnCt3lc@JNzd85d/AU)

No library functions required.

Comment: I think setting `m` to a parameter saves a couple bytes. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY7LDoIwEEXX8BUTjKaVqoW4q/gjhgWWVxM6NKW4IXx7BYML3d05c5J75amR0u8Uym4sK7gNrlT9ub2HP6hTz4X5miAzTNOp7i3RGRd4yYzQcUyFrdxoEbSYvUIHulBI1lDYRjKQbWHhuB6vR05hCoONVFiKMOh6bAAhg8FZ13fk4yU5g8PyZ5Bw@pXMn5T@ScYupTWJ9mXEYJ0Lhq58m8dFOHt/5dynbw "C (gcc) – Try It Online") -- truth be told, I was looking at "Tips for Golfing in C" and saw this; my C knowledge is minimal at best.

Comment: First I want to ask, why do you initialize `int m;` and only in the for-loop do `m=0`? You could have done `int m=0;for(;...` directly. In C however you can use some nice tricks, including the one stated (but incorrectly linked in the TIO I think) by _@Giuseppe_, as well as dropping the `return` like this: `m;f(n,p){for(m=0;n/=p;m++);n=m;}` [Try it online **32 bytes**](https://tinyurl.com/yacpkxo8)

Comment: Actually, using `,m` as parameter implicitly gives it the parameter-index as initial value (not sure if this is always the case, my C knowledge is limited). If it indeed is, `f(n,p,m){for(;n/=p;m++);n=m-2;}` can be used instead for **31 bytes**. [Try it online.](https://tio.run/##XY7LDoIwEEXX9CsmGE0rRYG4q/gjhgWWVxMYmlLcEL69UqML3c099yR3ZNxK6XYKZT9XNVwnW6nx1N3ID@rVY2Ouocg1H9jSjIYKPOdaDFHEBOZDnInVKbQwlAqpP0rTSg6yKw0cfXjeCwYLCT6kxkqQoB@xBYQcJmvs2NO3lxYcDlvPIU3YV9J/UvYnabONNjTcVyEH/yho5rmp7WwQEkFW5y5J4rIX) Oh, and welcome to PPCG! :)

Answer (score 0):

## [dc](https://www.gnu.org/software/bc/manual/dc-1.05/html_mono/dc.html), 30 bytes

```
sp0sm[dlplm1+dsm^!>M]dsMxlm1-p
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Lc4xCsMwDAXQ3adQyVgKsq1m7A0CHgMhgRJ1s1MTZcjtHcdoEU/8P3xei0VEsFgko6SJY47JPlnS8vgMM8tw1v@Vay2YaeeNKNTb29D6UeNZRuiOnxyQvuv@NwRviONpvFcQgsMmRw68yquoTnBNuuZ2uQA)

No logs in `dc` means no FP errors... Also means doing the thing repeatedly and testing to see when we go over, which... is not very golfy.

Straightforward, but here's the gist: `sp` stores our *p* value in `p`; `0sm` stores a zero in what will ultimately be our *m* value, `m`. Macro `M` duplicates what's left on the stack (*n*), loads `p`, loads `m`, spends a lot of bytes incrementing `m` (`lm1+dsm`), does the exponentiation `^` and tests if the result is less than or equal to *n* (left on stack). Keeps going so long as this is true, then loads `m`, subtracts 1, and prints it.

Answer (score 0):

## Java 8, <s>36</s> 34 bytes (with floating point errors on one test case)

```java
a->b->b+=Math.log(a)/Math.log(b)-b
```

-2 bytes thanks to *@OlivierGrégoire*.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##lY9Ba8JAEIXv@RVz3KVkG5P0ZBW8CB7Eg/RUPEyiSTddd5fdiRCKvz3dYigoghHm8ODx8b5p8IRxs//uS4Xewxql/okAPCHJEprQipakElWrS5JGi5Wm5ZDf79cfGl23sQeHZNwcKpj1GM@LcC@zNdKXUKZmyF//c8Hjop9GYda2hQqzw/rJyD0cgxHbkpO6/twButrzP0GAbefpcBSmJWFDS0qzSqC1qmM5v4SFDzrsjfPpIyLLnkby5ApJkxFMmqdXUDaKyZ5m8uRGbgQzSW6gyfDROTr3vw)

**Explanation:**

Java only has `Math.log(double val)` as builtin, which is basically *log<sub>10</sub>*. For *log<sub>n</sub>(val)* you'll have to use `Math.log(val)/Math.log(n)`.
So this is what the `Math.log(a)/Math.log(b)` does. The `b+=...-b` is used to cast the doubles of the `Math.log` to an integer, which is shorter than `a->b->(int)(Math.log(a)/Math.log(b))` (thanks *@OlivierGrégoire*).

---

## Java 10, <s>245</s> <s>240</s> <s>239</s> 231 bytes

```java
a->b->(int)(l(a)/l(b));double l(java.math.BigInteger v){int n=v.bitLength(),i=0,j=0;long t=1L<<52,M=t,m=0;for(;++i<54&&(j=n-i)>=0;M>>=1)m|=v.testBit(j)?M:0;return(n-1+Math.log((j>0&&v.testBit(j-1)?m+1:m)*1f/t)*1.4426950408889634);}
```

-5 bytes thanks to *@ceilingcat*.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##nZI7T8MwEIB3foWnyqaOcRIXFdIEiQEJiYiBETE4rRMcbKdKLkEI@tuLm3ZALQNiOZ@/e/geruUgg3r1tl0a2XUol9p9niFUe8x60IaVvVuCbhy7OyiL0WYlvLJbXd07UJVq6T8iDkqWoRKlaCuDrAgyrB0QbLAkFwYXhCSrpi@MQgb/lgQN5NMHIJcOrNDwoFwFr5hQnXJapzwxjasQpOHDYjGLaJ4CtZ6WTYuT6VQvZmIywXXqAk0yz/MsS0Niv3wyUB3casA1ucmvedIq6FuHXRBO810FpqkwrjM@mfxwDUJyY6fhtSXnYXkBXjIhosurGRd8Pp9fXcaCJJutn@7at6SXqAMJ/hgavULWDx4/Qatd9fyCZFt1ZLcHNG4EWT8gp97HCybJaLDjy9hSQWfHKI5PmeA04scwEhGNT2F8CgX38ccw5J6G@6ybMy/GXkbjvm6KduuR@6M4tPT00YGyrOmBrX3DYBy2rGRyvTYfv66ZDdL06rH0v4L8xc3/m0NJm@03)

**Explanation:**

To fix the floating point errors we'll have to use a BigInteger log. `a->b->(int)(l(a)/l(b))` is basically the same as before (note that `a` and `b` are now `java.math.BigInteger` inputs instead of `int`, so the same `b+=...-b` won't work here.

The separated log-method for better precision I got from [this Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9125512/1682559).

```java
double l(java.math.BigInteger v){
  // Get the minimum number of bits necessary to hold this value
  int n=v.bitLength(),
  // Index integers
      i=0,j=0;
  // Calculate the double-precision fraction of this numbers; as if the
  // binary point was left of the most significant '1' bit.
  // (Get the most significant 53 bits and divide by 2^53)
  // mantissa is 53 bits (including hidden bit)
  long t=1L<<52,M=t,m=0;
  for(;++i<54&&(j=n-i)>=0;M>>=1)m|=v.testBit(j)?M:0;
  // Round up if next bit is 1.
  // Add the logarithm to the number of bits, and subtract 1 because the
  // number of bits is always higher than necessary for a number
  // (i.e. log2(v)<n for every `v`)
  return(n-1+Math.log((j>0&&v.testBit(j-1)?m+1:m)*1f/t)*1.4426950408889634);}
  // Magic number converts from base e to base 2 before adding. For other
  // bases, correct the result, NOT this number!
```

Comment: Suggest `++i<54&(j=n-i)>=0;M/=2` instead of `++i<54&&(j=n-i)>=0;M>>=1`

Answer (score 0):

## Haskell, 30 bytes

```
f n p=head[x|x<-[0..],p^x>n]-1
```

Should be no round-off errors

Comment: 27 bytes - [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HclBCoMwEEbhq/xoFzMEg0PXeoK6cmktZFFQGqdBI@b2Ed09vje57ff1PudQarNrnD1Rq2wpfJjJCEsleXGzosHiQgd6J1Qtwh77uL4UD2zT/0CCMSiuU1x1Gz3LxIxBrJW6HvMJ "Haskell – Try It Online")

Answer (score 0):

## q, 42 bytes

```
{r::x;{$[r>=y xexp x;x;.z.s[x-1;y]]}[x;y]}
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Gol><>](https://tio.run/##S8/PScsszvj/39Mz2CdYA8gwMjHSMQYA), 7 bytes

```
IISLS(h
```

Can take the inputs seperated by a comma. (ex. [4,5], [6,8])

I'm pretty sure that this is the absolute smallest it can get..

Answer (score 0):

## [Runic Enchantments](https://github.com/Draco18s/RunicEnchantments/tree/Console), 13 bytes

```
i'LAi'LA,'fA@
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyrNy0z@/z9T3ccRhHXU0xwd/v83NDAwUDA0AAA)

Nothing fancy here. Reads an input and calls `Log` on it, repeats for the second input, divides, and floors. Runic is very permissive with typing, using implicit conversions where it makes sense to do so, with only a couple of explicit conversion operators (to-number, to-char, and dictionary-lookup).

Equivalent to `(int)Math.Floor((double)Math.Log(a) / Math.Log(b))`

Answer (score 0):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 3 bytes

```
$•⌊
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJBIiwiIiwiJOKAouKMiiIsIiIsIjQsIDVcbjMzLCA1XG4xMDAwLCAxMFxuNDAwLCAyIl0=)

```
$•⌊
$   # swap input
 •  # log
  ⌊ # floor
```

Answer (score 0):

## nroff, 95 bytes

It's stupid that I had to increment one more than expected, then decrement the value. I tried replacing initial value `.nr M -1` and deleting decrementing part but the result went something very crazy (e.g. `.F 4 5` returned -3 and `.F 1000 10` returned 1526194161). How does nroff really represent numerical value!?

```
.de F
.nr t 1
.nr M 0
.while \\nt<=\\$1 \\{.nr t \\nt*\\$2
.nr M \\nM+1\\}
.nr M \\nM-1
\\nM
..
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=Tc2xCsIwEAbgPU9xBaGgNOSSFDq0jtn6Bgei2FJBWqgVB_FJXDro4hv5Nl6SDk73f8ef3PN12F-6-dOPQ9uWZZqk7-vUZsV3J48NOCH7ESbAMGtQQt6607kBon4qK6IVcrzHkt-teaWXMrveINHjzxkKP4SUyxmSDizkotry3w6MCVn7bBVoxUAPbTUYho0wATnEHhdZhQcqFvpnRiTxxjzH-QM)

Answer (score 0):

## [Pyt](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt), 7 bytes

```
Đ←⇹ř^≥Ʃ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ARwA4/9weXT//8SQ4oaQ4oe5xZle4omlxqn//zI0Mwoz)

Couldn't use built-in log function because of floating-point inaccuracies. Takes N, then P.

```
Đ              implicit input; Đuplicate
 ←             get input
  ⇹            swap top two on stack
   ř           řangify
    ^          raise to power element-wise
     ≥         is N greater than or equal to each element?
      Ʃ        Ʃum; implicit print
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2) `L`, 2 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
Bḣ
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faGm0ko9S7IKlpSVpuhZLnB7uWLykOCm5GCqwYIkpl7ExhA0A)

Convert the second input to `B`ase-first input, then remove the `ḣ`ead (first item). The `L` flag takes the length.